# How to register UDF (python and scala) when using 'spark-sql' submit?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

It's possible to register UDF with code, in the context, before using sql api.
Spark proposes a command line tool: `spark-sql` to submit some SQL requests.

This tool use spark-submit with `--class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver`.

It's not possible to register a UDF before using `spark-sql`, but it's possible to add some jar or py-files.

What are the ways to use `spark-sql` with some registered functions?

Answer (score 1):

In general, JVM (Java / Scala) classes implementing the following interfaces:

- `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.{UDF, UDAF}`
- `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.{AbstractGenericUDAFResolver, GenericUDF, GenericUDTF}`
- `org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregateFunction`

can be registered using `CREATE FUNCTION` interface. Permanent functions will be available for all sessions.

There is no such capability for other UDF variants, including Python UDFs, ATM.